# Function works from command line but not within class

Tags: node.js, scope, bind, blockchain, leveldb

From the command line, this works:

```
let blockchain = new Blockchain();
var bla;
blockchain.getBlockHeightPromise().then(i => bla =  i);
```

//bla now has the correct value

From the command line, this doesn't work:

```
let blockchain = new Blockchain();
blockchain.addBlock(someBlock)
```

//Console log indicates that bla is undefined

Update: Why do results differ running from command line vs. calling the function from within the class?

//My code (abbreviated)

```
    class Blockchain {
    constructor() {
    }


    // Add new block
    async addBlock(newBlock) {
        var bla;
        this.getBlockHeightPromise().then(i => bla = i);
        console.log('bla: ' + bla);}
//Note addBlock needs to async because await db.createReadStream follows


    getBlockHeightPromise() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            let i = 0;

            db.createReadStream()
                .on('data', function () {
                    i++;
                })
                .on('error', function () {
                    reject("Could not retrieve chain length");
                })
                .on('close', function () {
                    resolve(i);
                });
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `getBlockHeightPromise` is aynchronous, so bla is set to i after the rest of your code has already been executed. See related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Right, so why doesn't this work? I'm only setting bla after the function resolves. this.getBlockHeightPromise().then(i => bla = i);    Perhaps console.log is firing before the function resolves?

Comment: You're setting bla after the promise resolves, yes, but the console statement after that is executed before the promise resolves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console statement is executed before the promise from `getBlogHeightPromise` is finished.

Use `await` to wait for the asynchronous method `getBlogHeightPromise` to resolve:

```
    // Add new block
    async addBlock(newBlock) {
        var bla = await this.getBlockHeightPromise();
        console.log('bla: ' + bla);
    }
```